# Data not getting retrieved from JSON

Tags: typescript

I want to do a calculation with the "inicio" number and the "fim" actually is subtracting the start(inicio) and the end(fim) but I'm not being able to retrieve the data, only the data of the entire JSON. Can someone help me to figure out why this is happening?

```
[
  {
    "codu": "80111",
    "dias": {
      "1": {
        "itens": [
          {
            "id": 0,
            "inicio": "09:00:00",
            "fim": "12:00:00",
            "show": 1,
            "local": "0"
          },
          {
            "id": 0,
            "inicio": "13:30:00",
            "fim": "18:00:00",
            "show": 1,
            "local": "0"
          }
        ]
      },
```

I tried the code:

```
async function disponibilidadesEscala (req: Request, res:Response) {
    let conn: any
    try {
        const query = `SELECT ea.escalas, u.nome from escalas_agenda ea left join usuarios u on u.codu = ea.codu `
        conn = await ormConn({database: req.body.jwt_content.data.usuclin, replica: true });
        const escalas = await conn.query(query);
        const escalasret = escalas.map( (escala) => {
            const data = (JSON.parse(escala.escalas.codu.dias.itens.inicio));
            return (data)
           
        })
```

If I use just

```
const data = (JSON.parse(escala.escalas));
return (data)
```

Retrieves all my data.

Answer (score 0):

```
        const data = (JSON.parse(escala.escalas.codu.dias.itens.inicio));
```

Your `itens` member isn't the direct child of `dias`; `dias` has a child key called `"1"` which has the `itens` value.

```
        const data = escala.escalas.codu.dias["1"].itens.inicio;
```

would let you access that, but `dias` probably has several children, so you would want to loop over them.

Comment: Do you have any error visible in the console? Please don't just say "it doesn't work". Try `        const data = (JSON.parse(escala.escalas).codu.dias.itens.inicio);`.

Comment: Sorry about that. It says TypeError: Cannot read property 'itens' of undefined

Comment: Because dias doesn't have a property itens. It has a child 1 and 1 has itens. What about "escala.escalas.codu.dias["1"].itens.inicio"?

Comment: I figured out how to retrieve from one day. But now the question is, how can I retrieve from all days?